# Pad Leading 0s to make it 5 digit counter for all mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, for-loop

I need to add a counter field in all documents , which will be of 5 digit , starting from `"00001"` to `"99999"` [This will be saved as String].

Till now I have written the below script , I need to pad leading 0s in case the counter is less than `"10000"`.

Script till now :

```
var count = 0;
db.addresses.find().forEach(function(item)
{
    item.addressId = count++;
    db.collection.save(item);
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of a javascript tweaking

```
var count = 0;
db.addresses.find().forEach(function(item)
{
    sample = "0000"+ count++;
    item.addressId = sample.slice(-5);
    db.collection.save(item);
});
```